# Efficiently simulating a BQP circuit and polynomial hierachy collapse

Tags: simulation, complexity-theory

If we were able to simulate a BQP (Bounded-error Quantum Polynomial time) circuit using a classical computer in an efficient manner, does it necessarily mean that the Polynomial Hierarchy (PH) would collapse?

If the implications are not known, any intuition-level answer is appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with the forrelation problem?

Comment: Hi @MarkSpinelli, never heard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be (and probably is) vacuously true, insofar as BQP problems are likely *not* efficiently simulatable with a classical computer, and [anything follows from a false premise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion), but we can maybe get some more intuition.

For example, quantum computers are not known to efficiently solve complete problems, not just for NP, not just for co-NP, but for *any* level of the polynomial hierarchy. Thus even if BQP were efficiently simulatable classically, BQP could not efficiently solve these complete problems, stopping the collapse of the hierarchy to that respective level.

But - it works both ways, and BQP is even weirder than the polynomial hierarchy!  Even if we lived in a world where the polynomial hierarchy collapsed, a quantum computer could *still* outpace a classical computer on some problems.

For example going back to Bernstein and Vazirani they defined a recursive version of their problem, and guessed that this was outside of the polynomial hierarchy (as an oracular problem).  Aaronson simplified the recursive Bernstein-Vazirani problem with his "forrelation problem" of determining whether one function has a large (or small) inner product with the Fourier transform of another function.  Raz and Tal [had shown](https://www.quantamagazine.org/finally-a-problem-that-only-quantum-computers-will-ever-be-able-to-solve-20180621/) that, as an oracle problem, the forrelation problem is completely *outside* of the polynomial hierarchy.

Thus, BQP and the entirety of the polynomial hierarchy are probably incomparable!

---

Added:

Fortnow and Rogers have a [1998 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/9811023) that explicitly claims in their abstract:

> 2. There exists a relativized world where P=BQP and the polynomial-time hierarchy is infinite.

To be quite honest I don't follow much of the paper, though.